# Libgdx Random images changing at every frame

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm quite new to Libgdx and I have encountered a problem when I want to display random images of playing cards. I have put all my sprites in an array list and used array.random to get a specific random playing card, however, the output would be all the playing card images all changing at every frame.

The Spades class

```
public class Spades extends CardTypes{
public Array<Sprite> spades = new Array<Sprite>(3);

public void cards(){

    spades.add(ace = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/AS.png")));
    spades.add(two = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/2S.png")));
    spades.add(three = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/3S.png"))); }
```

The GameScreen class

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

Spades spading = new Spades();

private Main game;

//create method
public GameScreen(Main game) {
    this.game = game;
    spading.cards();
}


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    game.getBatch().begin();
    game.getBatch().draw(spading.spades.random(),0,0);
    game.getBatch().end();

} }
```

The game.getBatch.draw() method would draw all my sprites at coordinates (0,0), changing at every frame. Is their anyway to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what happens. The `render` method is called every frame. You can add a timer, like this:

```
int amountOfFrames = 50;
int counter = amountOfFrames; // start from 50 so a new card is drawn right when the program begins

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    if(counter % amountOfFrames == 0) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1); // screen cleared
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // screen cleared
        Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        game.getBatch().begin();
        game.getBatch().draw(spading.spades.random(),0,0); // draws a new card
        game.getBatch().end();
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Then, every 50 frames a new card would be drawn. You can mess with that number to your liking. If you need anything further, comment.

Comment: Is there any way to display a specific random card?

Comment: @RMDevs Do you mean a specific card? From the array? Presuming the `Array<Sprite>` is `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array`, you can do `spade.get(index)`. So spade.get(0) would return the sprite for `spades/AS.png.`

Comment: Isn't there a way to display a random card from my array without all the cards rendering at every frame. When I added my sprites to my spades array (which is from com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array) I wanted to display a random card from my spades array, so I called the random() method from com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array in my render method and I thought it would display a single random card from my spades array. However, when I did run the program all the cards from my array would render at the same time, changing at every frame instead of displaying just one random card from my array.

Comment: Oh, I believe I understand now. Since the render function calls every frame, we shouldn't randomize it every frame. Since it's getting a random card every frame, a random card will be drawn every frame, each one different. You could add above the constructor, `Sprite card;`, and then to the constructor, `card = spading.spades.random();`, and then use `game.getBatch().draw(card, 0, 0);`

Comment: Also may I note, so you understand LibGDX more - Only one renders every frame, one random one. Not all, just one. and `render()` will repeat every frame, so every frame a new random card will be picked. the `Array.random()` function will just pick another random element of the array every time it is called, it won't choose one and go on with that for the rest of the program.